# How to overload a method?

Tags: java, methods

For this assignment I am supposed to write an overloaded version of `iquote()`, a method that displays the type of its argument and its argument enclosed in double quotation marks. Write three versions: one for int argument, one for a double argument and one for a String argument. I do not have to supply an application part. So far this is what I have. I feel like I am completely off track?

```
public class assign61 {

private String sQuote;
private int iQuote;
private double dQuote;

public String getSQuote()
{
    return sQuote;
    System.out.println( \"sQuote\" );" 

}

public int getIQuote()
{
    return iQuote;
    System.out.println( \"sQuote\" );" 
}       
public double getDQuote()
{
    return dQuote;
    System.out.println( \"sQuote\" );"          
}

}
```

Comment: Isn't the method supposed to take *arguments*?? All of yours have empty parenthesis.

Comment: Those methods don't have arguments, they all have different return types though.

Comment: @Kevin just letting you know in Java you cannot have anything after a return statement like that or it will not compile.

Comment: @RMT, actually if you have a return in a try{} block with a finally{} you can have code after the return.  But you are correct this code will not compile.

Comment: @Jzd, you are right but in my comment I said "have a return statement like that" meaning the way he has it

Comment: I think you're very new to programming. You'll need to do a lot of reading. But just to get you started, each of your functions should be of the same name and take different parameters (ie. getQuote(String str), getQuote(int i), getQuote(double d) ) for it to be considered method overloading. Also, if you want anything to be processed before a given "return" statement, you have to have to appear before that given "return" statement. So in the case of your System.out.println(), it will not be processed and possibly might not even compile.

Comment: How did you make it to assignment 61?

Answer (score 5):

You are off track because you are confusing the return type with an argument and your methods all have different names.   I would suggest reading again what method overloading is. (*Hint: same method name, different arguments*)

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't have any code after a `return` statement. A return means it leaves the function.

Next, if your teacher wants you to **overload** the function, that means you use the same function name, but accept different parameters. That is: `public void iquote(int n)`, `public void iquote(String s)`, and `public void iquote(double d)`.

So, you will not need to return anything in your `iquote()` functions. You will need to use `System.out.println()` to display your information.

Hopefully this helps.